# Customizing email ext plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, email-ext, jenkins-cli

I was trying to create a custom message for build fails, i wanted to add the name of the user whose commit break the build, the commit message and a brief summary of the error.
Can i write this in the 'Content' section in the configuration page or should i write a separate template file?
I am using svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this email ext plugin for a while. Here are an example for those who are new to this jenkins plugin, you can see this as a best practice and do some little modification as you need,enjoy it.

**Content Type**:  `HTML`
**Default Subject**: `[${BUILD_STATUS}]${JOB_NAME} Build #${BUILD_NUMBER} Total ${TEST_COUNTS,var="total"}/Fail ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}/Skip ${TEST_COUNTS,var="skip"}`

**Default Content**:

```
<b>Job URL</b><br/>
<a href="$${BUILD_URL}">${BUILD_URL}</a><br/>
<br/>
<b>Branch</b><br/>
${GIT_BRANCH}<br/>
<br/>
<b>Changes</b><br/>
${CHANGES,showPaths=true,format="[%d]-[%a] %m<br/>"}<br/>
<br/>
<b>Build Cause</b><br/>
${CAUSE}<br/>
<br/>
<b>Test Results</b><br/>
${FILE,path="rspec_results.html"}<br/>
<br/>
<b>Code Coverage</b><br/>
${FILE,path="coverage/rcov/index.html"}
<br/>
${FILE,path="tmp/metric_fu/output/stats.html"}
```

[image]

Then The ${CAUSE} variable will like this:

Comment: thanks a lot :)
how to add the name of the person whose commit made the build fail? (culprit) i am using svn

Comment: Usually we have the job set to triggered by SCM webhook push, in my example, I use Gitbucket. Once someone push code to Gitbucket, the ${CAUSE} variable in the **Default Content**  will be expanded to something like `Started by GitBucket push by Tom`. I've updated the answer accordingly.